# Unable to setup cisco vpn client in linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, cisco-vpn-client

I have configured cisco VPN client in a local machine in my network. When I start the vpn using vpnc, it is getting connected. But the problem is that, after that I'm not able to access my local sites because the VPN's nameserver got added. So, what I have did is added both VPN and my nameserver in the /etc/resolv.conf file and then started the VPN. But still its the issue exists. The OS I'm using is linux mint 13. Can anyone help in this??

I can do it if I add host entries in the /etc/hosts file, but that is not feasible for me as there are a lot of sites in my local network and adding entry for each is kind of hectic.

Any alternative solution is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it...

Added my local nameserver's IP and hostname in the /etc/hosts file and set the primary nameserver as VPN's NS.  And then the ldap authentication started working.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your VPN re-routes all of your traffic through the VPN, regardless of its local nature. You can correct this situation by adding a new routing rule that prevents local packets from being shipped overseas. Something like:

```
 sudo route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.0.1
```

Here I am assuming your network is 192.168.0.0 and your router is 192.168.0.1; adjust the command to suite your needs. Notice that routing rules are applied irrespective of their order (unlike **iptables**), choosing the most restrictive first, to the least restrictive.

Comment: I have already setup the route. But the problem is with the nameserver.

Comment: Which is the problem exactly? If you are not worried especially about secrecy, but just access, I can show you how to access your DNS servers outside the VPN. Or you cando that inside the VPN. Just give me a few more details, pls.

Comment: The VPN is working well and fine when it is started. But Iam unable to access the local network/DNS after that. The routing and all is properly done. I have set the route to access the local network and VPN separately. That is not a problem. Also I have added the nameserver needed to connect to VPN in the "resolv.conf" file. The problem is that, if I give the VPN nameserver first, I will be access the VPN network, but not my internal network. If I give my nameserver first, I will be able to access the internal network, but not the VPN.